# I'm using Homestead to make a VM and I have Laravel in a sub Folder, but can't access any sub URLs

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox

I'm using Homestead to make a VM and I have Laravel in a sub Folder, but can't access any sub URLs

This is the URL I have to go to in order to access the index for Laravel

```
 http://variux.app/minierp/public/
```

But this is the only site I can seem to access I am trying to access a view like this

```
Route::get('packages', 'PackagesController@index');
```

from my controller like this

```
public function index()
{
    $main = Package::all();
    return view('application.packages', compact('main'));
}
```

When I try to access the appropriate URL it does not work though.

```
http://variux.app/minierp/public/packages/
```

My Homestead.yaml has this sites pointer

```
folders:
   - map: ~/Documents/projects
     to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
   - map: variux.app
     to: /home/vagrant/code/
```

hosts system file has this

```
(my.vm.IP) variux.app
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error do you get? `404 not found`?

Comment: What is your `Homestead.yaml` setup for that site?

Comment: I'll edit to include my yaml and host pointer

Comment: my error says this --- No input file specified.